# Earbud as a microphone and phone/tablet as a speaker

Tags: tablet, microphone, speaker

Basically, I want my earbud to serve as a bluetooth microphone then connect it to my tablet to serve as a speaker. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: speakers can't work as microphones https://www.ac3filter.net/can-speakers-be-used-as-microphones

Answer (score 0):

Speakers in the old telephone (POTS) could have been used this way (because they were constructed differently). Modern earbuds, microphones and speakers are of a different construction.  Even if you could get them to work in a reverse fashion, they wont be very good.  They havent been designed for that.  The dynamic range and sound quality would be terrible.

Just buy headphones with microphones.  You can get over the ear, around the ear versions.  Cheap ones are not that expensive and will still give you better quality sound than your current thinking..